# How can I distribute my OSX Cocoa app with static library?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, libraries

I am using SQLite3 with FTS modules and I want to place it in application bundle. Is this correct way? How can I make Xcode search headers and library in application bundle rather that in specific path on filesystem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any static libraries referenced by the project will get linked into the application binary. There's no need to distribute the static libraries in the app bundle.

Comment: I created Static Library Target in my main workspace, and added this lib to Target Dependency and Link Binary With Libraries sections for main target. With this combination app is exported from Xcode without static library.

Comment: You can check whether the static library was successfully linked using the `nm` tool. Run it as `nm -a <YourApp>.app/Contents/MacOS/<YourApp>` in Terminal and you'll see entries like `0000000052976e95 - 03 0001   OSO MacApp/Build/Products/Debug/libMacStaticLib.a(MacStaticLib.o)` for any linked libraries.

Comment: Guess "linked" doesn't mean "copied" here?

Comment: In a way it does. The linker embeds the static library's object file into the application binary. Are you sure you're referencing `libSqlite3.a` (the static variant) and not `libSqlite3.dylib` (the dynamic variant)? `otool -L <YourApp>.app/Contents/MacOS/<YourApp>` will list any libraries that are linked dynamically.

Comment: @dig There is no need for a new target unless you want to build the library.  If you already have the .a file, then just add it and the headers to your project (likely in a new group).  Make sure the library is mentioned in the Linking build phase.

Comment: @bbum I build it from source

Comment: @neilco https://gist.github.com/nt9/7695615 I build my library with custom name libSQLiteWithFTS, however from output I see that original Mac SQLite is linked and also it is linked dynamically? Or that just different names like system name/Xcode name? I also see copy of my library exported in .xcodearchive in Products/usr/local/lib/libSQLiteWithFTS.a

Comment: You're not linking against libSQLiteWithFTS.a at all. At least that's what the output in the gist suggests.

Comment: @neilco Yes, seems like that. Library is added to Xcode (see updated answer with screenshots).

Comment: @neilco Did you run nm -a against debug version of you application?